# object to string[]

Tags: c#, list, object

I am working with some existing C# code. Essentially, I have a variable which is a List of objects.

Each of the objects, in turn is a string[n]. I know n, and the value is the same for all the objects in the list. What I need to know is how to loop over the list of objects and get, for each item, a

```
string[n]
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to convert each single object into a an array of strings.

Comment: why would you want to convert anything? Do you have a `List<object>` or `List<string[]>`? Show some code. I'm pretty sure iterating over loops is covered in every C# tutorial you can get.

Comment: `foreach(var arr in list.Cast<string[]>())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question as how to cast an object of compile time type `Object` to its run time type of `string[]`. You do that like so:

```
Object obj = ...;
string[] arr = (string[]) obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just casting the `object` to `string[]`?

```
string[] arr = (string[])listOfObjects[x];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
foreach(string[] strings in listOfStringArrays.Cast<string[]>())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). It projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var resultantArray = myarray.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```